# Convert UTC time to hours, minutes, and AM/PM format in javascript

Tags: javascript, time, utc

Given a UTC time, what is a simple way of converting it to a format in hours, minutes, and AM/PM (e.g. '3:30 PM')?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Tried getHours() and getMinutes(), and there are probably some hacky ways to reformat them. Know moment.js is out there and considering to use it, but wondering if anything simpler exists.

Comment: With fewest number of lines!

Comment: You should check out [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/). It takes the pain away. Ex. `moment.utc(new Date()).format("h:mm A");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// d = new Date(utc);
var hour = d.getHours() == 0 ? 12 : (d.getHours() > 12 ? d.getHours() - 12 : d.getHours());
var min = d.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes();
var ampm = d.getHours() < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
var time = hour + ':' + min + ' ' + ampm;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

var a_p = "";
var d = new Date();

var curr_hour = d.getHours();

if (curr_hour < 12)
   {
   a_p = "AM";
   }
else
   {
   a_p = "PM";
   }
if (curr_hour == 0)
   {
   curr_hour = 12;
   }
if (curr_hour > 12)
   {
   curr_hour = curr_hour - 12;
   }

var curr_min = d.getMinutes();

document.write(curr_hour + " : " + curr_min + " " + a_p);

//-->
</script>
```

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/formatting_time_using_javascript.php

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function, you can change a utc time in any format:-

```
var  getDateString = function(date, format) {
            var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            getPaddedComp = function(comp) {
                return ((parseInt(comp) < 10) ? ('0' + comp) : comp)
            },
            formattedDate = format,
            o = {
                "y+": date.getFullYear(), // year
                "M+": months[date.getMonth()], //month
                "d+": getPaddedComp(date.getDate()), //day
                "h+": getPaddedComp((date.getHours() > 12) ? date.getHours() % 12 : date.getHours()), //hour
                "m+": getPaddedComp(date.getMinutes()), //minute
                "s+": getPaddedComp(date.getSeconds()), //second
                "S+": getPaddedComp(date.getMilliseconds()), //millisecond,
                "t+": (date.getHours() >= 12) ? 'PM' : 'AM'
            };

            for (var k in o) {
                if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format)) {
                    formattedDate = formattedDate.replace(RegExp.$1, o[k]);
                }
            }
            return formattedDate;
        };
```

Now you can use it to format any date object like:-

```
 getDateString(new Date(), "h:m:s:t")

o/p: "01:34:22:AM"


 getDateString(new Date(), "y:M:d")
 o/p:- "2014:Jun:20"

 getDateString(new Date(), "y/M/d h:m:s:t")
 o/p:- "2014/Jun/20 01:34:22:AM"
```